# How to redirect "continue to payment" to another url with checkout json parameters in shopify

Tags: shopify, payment, checkout

I want to redirect to continue to payment to another my custom URL, where I get money from a customer by easy paisa or jazz cash, then redirect to a thank you page.
I am working in Shopify.
I want to use third party payment gateway, that Shopify not providing yet. such as Easypaisa and jazz cash.
Anyone has an idea.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a third party payment gateway with the help of [hosted payment gateway](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/hosted-payment-sdk). To do so, now you need to request for the third party payment gateway to Shopify in [Shopify Hosted Payment SDK Request Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe7aB9HkDQ6z3OgNYanFUUFMofntNlsCmNfwT_pmzfD9Jqi4A/viewform).